# Adjust header & content with padding only on header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, padding

I have a problem because in my code i have an header with padding(left & right at 8%), but on the content box i dont have padding, and when i reduce the firefox window the content box have not the same width than the header (because padding on the header change this).

So I want to the box content have always the same width than the header, and keep dimensions of the slidebar.

in the content right of the slide bar, I have tried to put the same padding but that does not change because the contentbox have a defined width.

This is a code example:

```
<header>
     <div id="logo"></div>
</header>

<div id="box">
    <div id="slidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

thats the JSFIDDLE :
https://jsfiddle.net/t2h839dt/
(if you reduce the preview window on JSFIDDLE, you see the problem (not same width for header and box content).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems partially responsive. First of all you should decide which approach you are going to do? either fixed or responsive layout.
Please try the below link is for fixed layout.

```
[jsfiddle][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/hLsaotco/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so i understand that i need to use fixed (with px) or % but only one kind for placing element. it's not a badway if i do all with px and i use media queries for one or two resolution (mobile and ipad for example) ?